# SPFx workbench.html is not generated

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, workbench

I'm trying to setup a local development environment for SharePoint Framework to develop web parts. I've followed the microsoft guides for [setting up SPFx dev environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment) and [build your first web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

I start my local web server with `gulp serve` and a `temp` folder is created containing `manifests.js` and `manifests.json` but no `workbench.html`. The server is up and running and i can browse files in the directory.

Also what I'm having a hard time understanding from the guides are how the **hosted workbench** and local workbench are working together. Is it a necessity to have a hosted workbench to run the local one?

**Things I've tried**

1. [Changed serve port from default](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2253)
2. Tried different LTS versions of node v14. (currently using 14.18.3)
3. [Added set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2333)

**Contents of my** `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.13.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.9": "0.4.47",
    "gulp": "~4.0.2",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check below steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local hosted workbench has been removed with new version of SPFx.

You can only run and test web part in SharePoint hosted workbench.

follow the below steps to configur.

1. Locate and open the file ./config/serve.json in your project.
2. Locate the property initialPage:
3. Change the enter-your-SharePoint-site domain to the URL of your
   SharePoint tenant and site you want to use for testing. For example:
   https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/_layouts/workbench.aspx.

For more details refer the below Microsoft Docs

[Update hosted work bench URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part#update-your-projects-hosted-workbench-url)